# Parsing xml CDATA in c# in windows 8 phone app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read to some data in XML format which is CDATA in my windows 8 phone app. Here is a sample of the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE HolyQuran [
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran TranslationID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Writer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Language CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran LanguageIsoCode CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST HolyQuran Direction (rtl|ltr) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT HolyQuran (Chapter+)>
<!ATTLIST Chapter ChapterID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Chapter ChapterName CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Chapter (Verse+)>
<!ATTLIST Verse VerseID CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Verse (#PCDATA)>
  ]>
<!-- This SQL Query Generated at 22 November 2013 01:44 (UTC) from
  www.qurandatabase.org -->
<HolyQuran TranslationID="59" Writer="Yusuf Ali" Language="English"
    LanguageIsoCode="eng" Direction="ltr">
<Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[In the name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most
                              Merciful.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[Praise be to Allah, the Cherisher and Sustainer
                              of the worlds;]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="3"><![CDATA[Most Gracious, Most Merciful;]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="4"><![CDATA[Master of the Day of Judgment.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="5"><![CDATA[Thee do we worship, and Thine aid we seek.
                             ]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="6"><![CDATA[Show us the straight way,]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="7"><![CDATA[The way of those on whom Thou hast bestowed Thy
                             Grace, those whose (portion) is not wrath, and who go
                             not astray.]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
</HolyQuran>
```

I want to get a data structure which contains the ChapterName, ChapterID and a List of all the verse contents and their corresponding VerseIDs. Please note that by verse content, I mean the CDATA. I need to use XDocument but I cannot figure out how to parse this complex XML.

I will greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: I got this from an earlier post:

            var items1 = xDoc.Root
                            .Elements("Chapter")
                            .Elements("Verse")
                            .Select(v => new
                            {
                                Id = (int)v.Attribute("VerseID"),
                                Content = (string)v
                            }).ToList();

Comment: What did you get from an earlier post?

Comment: It reads in all the verses but I have no way of finding out the ChapterName. I need a data structure which represents a single chapter with its ChapterName, ChapterID, and all the verses along with their verse IDs. Thank you!

Comment: sorry for the badly formed comments!

Comment: No it's fine. However, it seems like there is not a single CDATA in the XML sample you have provided. Could you please clarify which sections you are talking about?

Comment: I am talking about the Verse section. I need  a data structure which represents the whole chapter, with a list of all the verses(the CDATA) and their corresponding VerseIds. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my fault I missed that CDATA. It's pretty simple, just a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a `Chapter` and a `Verse` class:

```
public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Verse> Verses { get; set;}
}
public class Verse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Contents { get; set; }
    public static Verse FromXElement(XElement element)
    {
        return new Verse { Id = (int)element.Attribute("VerseID"), 
            Contents = element.Value };
    }
}
```

Then it's simpler:

```
XDocument doc = //get your document
XElement chapter = doc.Root.Element("Chapter");
Chapter result = new Chapter { Id = (int)chapter.Attribute("ChapterId"), 
    Name = (string)chapter.Attribute("ChapterName"), 
    Verses = chapter.Elements().Select(Verse.FromXElement).ToList() }
```

(I put the `FromXElement` method because it looks neater, you can inline it if you want though)

Comment: Thank you so much! I get this error when I run it:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<webreq.Verse>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<webreq.Verse>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Its this line:
    Verses = chapter.Elements().Select(Verse.FromXElement) }

Comment: I got it to compile after casting it as (List<Verse>). But now when, I run the app, it breaks!

Comment: @hmanso02 So sorry, I forgot to use `ToList`. It's been fixed now :)

Comment: How do I make so that I have a list of all the chapters in the XML doc? For example:
<HolyQuran TranslationID="59" Writer="Yusuf Ali">
<Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
    <Verse VerseID="1"><![CDATA[In the name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most                              Merciful.]]></Verse>
</Chapter>
<Chapter ChapterID="1" ChapterName="The Opening">
                        Merciful.]]></Verse>
    <Verse VerseID="2"><![CDATA[Praise be to Allah, the Cherisher and Sustainer
</Chapter>
</HolyQuran>
This has two chapters. Is it possible to make a list of chapters?

Comment: @hmans: Use foreach with xdoc.Root.Elements. I would help more but I'm on mobile, sorry :/